# Exporting multiple functions with module.exports in ES6

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, module-export

I'm building a node.js application and I'm trying to put all my mongodb logic in a seperate file. At this time this file only has one function to initialize the mongodb connection. I want to export all the functions from this file using `module.exports`.

My mongo file looks as follows:

```
import { connect } from "mongoose";

const run = async (db: string): Promise<void> => {
  await connect(db, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  });
};

module.exports = {
  run
};
```

I want to use this run function in index.ts and im trying to import it as an ES6 module but I can't get it working with the above code.

How I'm importing:

index.ts:

```
import * as mongo from "./mongo";
```

Trying to call my run method:

```
mongo.run('dburl');
```

This throws following error: '`property run does not exist`'

Now I have found a solution to this problem by adding an extra export before my run declaration:

```
export const run = async (db: string): Promise<void> => {...}
```

**I don't understand why I have to do this as I'm already exporting this function inside `module.exports`, am I importing it wrong in my index file or is there a better way of doing this?**

Comment: Try using `import mongo from "./mongo";`

Comment: `module.exports` is common.js, not ES6, you could have done `export { run }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MDN: JavaScript Modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules)

There are different types of modules in JS.

ES6 Modules use the `export` keyword. You can import all the exports like this `import * as ... from "..."` or import individual exports via `import { ... } from "..."`

CommonJS modules use `modules.exports` which is equivalent to `export default` in ES6 modules. These you can import like this `import ... from "..."`.

So when you use `modules.exports` you would either have to change your import to:

`const mongo = require('./mongo');`

Or you could change your export to:

`export { run }`

Comment: You can't do `import mongo from "./mongo";` in a CommonJS module. Did you mean `const mongo = await import('./mongo');`?

Comment: You can't do it in a CommonJS module, but he's importing in an ES6 module

Comment: Yes, but if they wants to export through `module.exports` ("*So when you use `modules.exports`...*"), then their module has to be converted to a CommonJS module (although using ES6 exports would be better)

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right...I'll change my answer